# What is this thing on my wall? Some sort of alarm?

Tags: alarm

On the wall in the hallway of my new house is this thing:

[image: Photo of the thing]

It's about 6 inches to a side and mounted right at the top of the wall.

I assumed it was a wireless chime for a (since removed) doorbell, so I opened up the case to find the mounting screws.

What I actually found, was *this*:

[image: Photo of the thing with the cover removed]

I'm guessing the warning sticker indicates that it's mains powered. It also looks too complicated to be a doorbell chime.

Finally, there are a couple of little buttons next to the black cylinders (capacitors?). One of them is labelled self-test, which makes me think it might be an alarm of some kind. We do have a burglar alarm, but this doesn't appear to be related. I guess it could be a smoke alarm, but there's one quite close by. Or perhaps it's a carbon monoxide alarm, but there aren't any things close by that burn anything.

I could try to dismantle it more, but am reluctant to do so until I know how to isolate it and discharge those capacitors.

So... I'm kinda stumped. Anyone got any ideas?

---

*Edited to add some pictures.*

Having been reassured by the comments, I pulled the black things free. They are indeed Li batteries:

[image: Closeup of the black battery packs]

There are no real labels to speak of on the inside of the front cover:

[image: Photo of the inside of the front cover]

But there are these marks, which I presume are just about the batch and type of plastic:

[image: Closeup of markings]

---

*Edited a second time to add the smoking gun...*

As suggested by NoSparksPlease in the comments, I disconnected the batteries. The burglar alarm control panel immediately started complaining about a tamper alarm on the indoor siren:

[image: Closeup of warning on alarm system]

Comment: why don't you read the label on the black cylinder before you start worrying about discharging capacitors

Comment: The top of the circuit board has a jack that appears to be a connector for the batteries. If this device is connected to a security alarm when you disconnect the batteries you should get a "trouble" signal on your alarm panel. Depending on what panel  you have it might tell you device name, or just loop number, and you would need to research installers documentation.

Comment: High voltage is likely associated with the strobe light, which has a very distinct "fire/smoke alarm" feel to it. There may, in fact be a line voltage connection as well, but that actually isn't normally described as high voltage.

Comment: Also curious what words may be obstructed by the battery jack.

Comment: Are there any labels, marks, stamps, etc in the battery compartment? Also, it appears that the inner cover with the scary yellow sticker could come off with the removal of 3 screws in the 3 small, deep holes. If there are screws there, try removing (carefully - see scary yellow sticker!) that inner cover to see if there's anything interesting behind it.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease Your tip got me the answer! Disconnecting the batteries resulted in my alarm panel complaining about a tamper alarm on the indoor siren. So I guess that's what this unit does. If you want to add an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a DSC PowerG Wireless indoor siren.

The batteries are the sole source of power.  It's a good idea to replace them on the expiry date, which we can't see but you should have a look now that you have them in your hand, or six years after the installation date, which we can see in the photo.

The high voltage warning pertains to the strobe light.  There probably is a capacitor on the logic board that you would not enjoy discharging manually. That's why there is an interior cover that allows you access to the batteries.

Here's some gratuitous advice: You probably have other wireless components in your alarm system and ADT expects you to keep track of battery life and replace them.  It's a good idea to open up all the window, door, fire, heat, and other sensors to check the battery installation dates and if you bought the house with this system already installed, to just replace them all regardless.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks so much. I'll start checking the other components today

Answer (score 2):

The black cylinders are probably backup batteries. Notice the quick disconnects.
It may be a smoke/carbon monoxide detector or an alarm. It’s hard to tell.

Is there a burglar alarm system?  If not it’s probably a smoke alarm.

Comment: Yeah I can make out the words "Lithium Cell Pack" on the top one. Agree some sort of alarm.